# How to generate unique string of fixed length given an already saved list of filenames?

Tags: python, unique

How to generate a new unique string of fixed length given (already generated using the same method) a list of saved strings in python?

See code below. I need to run it multiple times (potentially as large as the size of the complete set of possible strings (say of length 8 characters)).

```
strs= load_strings()
#strs= ['sasasafs', 'fdgfdgsa', '43f43y4f', ...]

new_str = generate_new_unique_string(strs) #how to implement this function?
strs.append(new_str)
save_strings(strs)
```

Comment: Check out `NamedTemporaryFile` from Python's standard `tempfile` module.

Comment: Can anyone say who has given the negative vote without a comment who don't know the reason himself/herself?

Comment: I didn't downvote this time, but you're likely to get downvotes if you ask "how do I do XYZ?" without showing your own attempt to do XYZ and pinpointing the error/roadblock that is preventing you from succeeding. See the FAQ and "how to ask" docs. SO is intended to be a site that educates/helps people get unstuck, not a site that does your homework for you.

Comment: First of all, imho, everyone must agree to this point that it also takes sometime to improve a question (most likely more time than to put a downvote without a comment).

Comment: I doubt you're going to potentially run the check on the size of the complete set of possible strings because, for example, limiting the possible number of characters to 62 (upper and lowercase ascii + digits) is 218,340,105,584,896 eight character long filenames (+ all the shorter ones). I believe this indicates that your whole approach is wrong.

Comment: @martineau: The lame way to do this is a) to generate a uuid and check if matches with the already existing ones. If not matches spit that uuid, else goto a). But is there an easy way/better way in python?

Comment: Since you only need to check if a newly generated random filename has been used yet, you could keep a `set` of those already generated (in addition or instead of a `list` of them), which would make membership testing O(1).

Comment: @jez : I don't understand what makes you this presumption that any question without an answer is a homework to you.

Comment: The question isn't clear. If you want a random string that won't clash with other strings, why not use `uuid.uuid4()`?

Answer (score 0):

use os to check if file name exist plus use random to generate some random text fro random name

check file exist

```
import os.path
from os import path

path.exists("guru99.txt")
```

random name (in example length of 7 character)

```
import random

name = ""
for i in range(7):
    name += chr(random.randint(48,90))

print(name)
```